# Running various make targets from sublime text 2

Tags: makefile, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm doing mostly webdevelopment and recently decided to give sublime 2 a try.

For my typical projects I have a `Makefile` with multiple targets. (E.g.: *javascript* --> compress javascript, *deploy* --> upload to server, *style* --> build css from less, *coffee* --> compile coffeescript to javascript, etc.)

Sublime recognizes the make file and run the 'all' target works perfectly fine. But for large projects running all the stuff takes far to long so I would like to configure sublime, so it build only a specific make target.

Is there any way to configure Sublime to run only the make targets I want. Is there any possibility to do this with file in the project root (and tracked via git), so the build would even work on another computer?

Comment: Do you know if `make all` is the actual command generated from sublime or if it´s just `make`, which will build the first target in the makefile?

Comment: It think sublime just calls make. I'll check this later. (I name the first target 'all' so it doesn't make a difference for my make files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current state of Sublime it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for but check out this forum, may give you a bit of an insight into multiple builds:-

[Sublime Forum: multiple commands in build system?](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4370)

if not then you could look and ask on the forums there, it will be more specialized for these sorts of features :)

This is from there and may be what your looking for?

:- "Unfortunately, there is no support for multiple commands in a build system. I ran into this issue when working with java. Your best option is to make a bash file with the commands and have a build system that runs the bash file. I'm not a expert when it comes to build systems, so that's as far as I can help.

Hope that points you in the right direction."

so maybe you can point at the specific "make" commands that you want to use...